# I hosted simple HTML CSS page on AWS S3 as a website but on the live web page everywhere in text " -" is displayed as " âˆ’ " character. I

Tags: html, css, amazon-s3

[image: This is how text looks on S3]

I have attached image screenshot of page hosted on S3. It works fine on local environment. This doesn't seem to be font issue.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution may be to set the charset via meta-tag inside the head-section of the html.

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked.